# Recursive explanation

Tags: java, recursion

Today in the class of Java the professor came up with this example but I really couldn't understand very well the process how to go through this method in order to get the result = 4. Could any body please put some lines as clear as possible how is that this method is solved?? Thank you
Ok so this is the method:

```
public static int mystery(int[] values, int start, int value)
{
    if(start == values.length) {
        return value;
    }
    else
        return Math.max(value, mystery(values, start+1, values[start]));
}
```

Comment: What inputs were supposed to give the result `4`?

Comment: You should also include the values of the input parameters (`values`, `start` and `value` respectively, otherwise it's hard to explain what's going on. Although I hazard a guess that `value` and `start` are both 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result isn't 4, but the maximum in the array.

It goes like this:

`values` is the array of elements.

`start` is the current index.

`value` is the current maximum.

If the current index is past the length of the array, return the current maximum. This is the first line of code and the halting condition.

Otherwise, return the maximum between the current maximum and the maximum of the array past the current index. Which will, recursively, ultimately return the maximum in the array.

You initially call this function with `start = 0` and `value = 0`.

Assume `values = [2,5,1]`.

```
mystery ( [2,5,1], 0 , 0 ) ->
  start (0) != values.length (3) ->
  return max (0, mystery( [2,5,1], 1, 2 ) ->
      mystery ( [2,5,1], 1, 2 ) ->
        start (1) != values.length ->
        return max (2, mystery( [2,5,1], 2, 5 ) ->
            mystery ([2,5,1], 2, 5) ->
            start(2) != values.length ->
                return max(5, mystery( [2,5,1], 3, 2) ->
                   start(3) == values.length ->
                   return value (1)
                -> return max(5,1)
            -> return 5
         -> return max(2,5)
       -> return 5
   -> return max(0,5)
-> return 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example that you can play with: (it is in javascript, but functions the same way)

http://jsfiddle.net/rEZ66/1/

Basically, the function `mystery` takes the array as input, and loops though each element return the maximum element.

When it runs, the recursive function compares the highest value it has found so far (`value`) to the current element of the array(`values[start]`), and loops again using the current largest value, against the next element `start+1`